# How can I stop access to all NSView in a window after showing a new NSView on the whole window?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

Let's say I have n number of views in a window but I want to restrict access to all of them and show a signInView above that and till the signIn is completed it should not let access to any other view under it. But at the moment, even if I can show the signInView(), the views under that are accessed.

I am showing the sign in view in the window like:

```
vc = SignInViewController()

self.view.window?.contentViewController?.view.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Comment: Use the fast enumeration with contentView's subView array.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessed", which events do you want to block? Does the `SignInViewController` view cover all the other views? How about a sheet?

Comment: @ElTomato Do you have any example or can you explain in brief? I would really appreciate it, if you can

Comment: @Willeke No I cannot use sheet as I just want to block one or more views in a window and let the user use other views if they want to. I want to restrict use of some particular NSView loading the signInviewController.view

Comment: I don't even know under what class you are writing code.

Comment: Why don't you disable the views?

Comment: This is not correct way. You should swap/exchange contentView. Not hide or disable views